# How to save HTML (Jsoup) to a File in Android

Tags: java, android, html

I download HTML file from Web and now I want to save it to internal storage. I know how to save an XML file, because there I use `InputStream`. But here, I have a `Document`.

**CODE SNIPPET from DownloadHTML.java:**

```
           try {
                Log.d("URL" , URL);
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

                temperature = doc.select("tbody").select("tr").select("td.t");
                date = doc.select("tbody").select("tr").select("td.meteoSI-th");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How can I save `Document doc` to a File in internal storage of my Android Device? 
I have tried reading [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) from official Android page but it did not help me in my case. I think there is similar solution as to saving XML file, but can't get my head around.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the document contents as a String by using `doc.toString()`

Then write the string to a file.

Probably the easiest thing to do once you have created the file as shown in the tutorial that you linked to is to use a [PrintWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintWriter.html), something like:

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
printWriter.print(doc.toString());
```